# How to aucomatically track changes in a daily full backup table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, change-tracking

Every day I have a table A (same name with same schema) which is a full backup one without datastamp.

Table Fields:

Code,
Name,
Salary

What I need is to **automatically** keep all the changes on the table A.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, much appreciated in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to compare today's table with yesterdays backup and record the differences. Is this accurate? Or do you want a real-time record of changes, like an audit trail?

Answer (score 0):

Run a difference query on it and save to a new table.  You can do this automatically through triggers.